# Calculate time difference between observations for some rows only

Tags: r

I've got a dataset that looks like this:

```
 id      date         outcome
 ny21    2021-03-01   0
 ny21    2021-02-01   1
 ny21    2021-01-01   0
 ch67    2021-08-09   0
```

I can calculate the time difference between rows grouped by `id` in the following way:

```
 unlist(tapply(df$date, INDEX = df$id, FUN = function(x) c(0, `units<-`(diff(x), "days"))))
```

However, I also want to calculate the time difference between rows grouped by `id`, where `outcome == 1`. If the current row has `outcome == 1`, and no such previous row exists, I want to put 0. So, something like this:

```
 id      date         outcome  days_since_outcome_1
 ny21    2021-03-01   0        28
 ny21    2021-02-01   1        0
 ny21    2021-01-01   0        0
 ch67    2021-08-09   0        0
```

How can I do this?

EDIT:

In some situations, there are more than one `outcome == 1` per `id`. In this case, I would like the code to calculate the difference since the latest match (not the first match). Something like this:

```
 id      date         outcome  days_since_outcome_1
 ny21    2021-05-01   1        30  # this is days since 2021-04-01
 ny21    2021-04-01   1        59  # this is days since 2021-02-01
 ny21    2021-03-01   0        28  # this is days since 2021-02-01 (first match)
 ny21    2021-02-01   1        0
 ny21    2021-01-01   0        0
 ch67    2021-08-09   0        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `match` get the corresponding `date` where `outcome = 1` for a `id`. Change the values which are before the `outcome` date to 0 along with those values which do not have any value with `outcome = 1`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(days_since_outcome_1 = as.integer(date - date[match(1, outcome)]), 
         days_since_outcome_1 = replace(days_since_outcome_1, 
               days_since_outcome_1 < 0 | is.na(days_since_outcome_1), 0)) %>%
  ungroup


#   id    date       outcome days_since_outcome_1
#  <chr> <date>       <int>                <dbl>
#1 ny21  2021-03-01       0                   28
#2 ny21  2021-02-01       1                    0
#3 ny21  2021-01-01       0                    0
#4 ch67  2021-08-09       0                    0
```

For larger datasets, you can try `data.table` -

```
setDT(df)
df
df[, days_since_outcome_1 := as.integer(date - date[match(1, outcome)]), id]
df[, days_since_outcome_1 := replace(days_since_outcome_1, 
            days_since_outcome_1 < 0 | is.na(days_since_outcome_1), 0)]
df
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! Do you know, though, if it's possible to do the same with tapply (or other faster method)? I prefer `dplyr` usually, but my dataset is 10+ million rows, and I found  `dplyr` to be slow for similar operations for for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `tapply` is going to be any faster than `dplyr`.  Maybe `data.table` is better option. Try the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you - that is indeed much faster. One last thing, if you have the time - I've noticed there is an issue if there is more than one `outcome == 1` per `id`. The calculation calculates the days since the **first** match, rather than the match in the prior row. Is there a way to change this? I've added an edit to the post to explain this